# Need output Based on Count OR Weights based on TimeDifference

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

```
TID   StartTime                   Uid   WId
1     2011-06-06 09:30:00.000     10    1.5
2     2011-06-06 09:40:00.000     10    3.5
3     2011-06-06 09:50:00.000     10    1.0
4     2011-06-06 10:45:00.000     10    2.5
5     2011-06-06 10:50:00.000     10    1.5
6     2011-06-06 10:55:00.000     10    0
7     2011-06-06 11:30:00.000     10    0
8     2011-06-06 11:35:00.000     10    0
9     2011-06-06 11:40:00.000     10    0
10    2011-06-06 11:43:00.000     10    0
11    2011-06-06 11:20:00.000     11    7.0
12    2011-06-06 11:30:00.000     11    1.0
```

I have the data in Table TblTask , I need to write a query to calculate (sum(Wid) or Count(TID's)) based on time difference of each Starttime with another starttime having time difference 1 hour or close to 1 hr Group by UID.

For example take first start time(2011-06-06 09:30:00.000); the nearest start time having <=1 hr is (2011-06-06 10:30:00.000) (If the SUM(Wid) >=5.0 OR Count of Rows >=5). Here Weights are (1.5+3.5+1.0=6.0)
 First 3 rows TID's (1,2,3) as weight>=5 we need to show the records and 
 TID's (3,4,5)  Here Weights are (1.0+2.5+1.5=5.0)
 For TID'd(4,5,6,7,8,9,10) Here Count (TID's is 7) So i want display all the records from 4 to 10

For TID's(5,6,7,8,9,10) as Count (TID's is > 5 ) i want display all the records from 5 to 10

For TID's(6,7,8,9,10) as Count (TID's is = 5 ) i want display all the records from 6 to 10

For TID 11 as WID > 5 i want to display record 11

For TID's (11,12) as WID >5 again i want to display record 11 and 12

Desired output will be:

```
TID    StartTime                 Uid  
1     2011-06-06 09:30:00.000    10    
2     2011-06-06 09:40:00.000    10     
3     2011-06-06 09:50:00.000    10   
3     2011-06-06 09:50:00.000    10    
4     2011-06-06 10:45:00.000    10    
5     2011-06-06 10:50:00.000    10    
4     2011-06-06 10:45:00.000    10    
5     2011-06-06 10:50:00.000    10    
6     2011-06-06 10:55:00.000    10    
7     2011-06-06 11:30:00.000    10    
8     2011-06-06 11:35:00.000    10    
9     2011-06-06 11:40:00.000    10    
10    2011-06-06 11:43:00.000    10    
5     2011-06-06 10:50:00.000    10    
6     2011-06-06 10:55:00.000    10    
7     2011-06-06 11:30:00.000    10    
8     2011-06-06 11:35:00.000    10    
9     2011-06-06 11:40:00.000    10    
10    2011-06-06 11:43:00.000    10    
6     2011-06-06 10:55:00.000    10    
7     2011-06-06 11:30:00.000    10    
8     2011-06-06 11:35:00.000    10    
9     2011-06-06 11:40:00.000    10    
10    2011-06-06 11:43:00.000    10    
11    2011-06-06 11:20:00.000    11 
11    2011-06-06 11:20:00.000    11    
12    2011-06-06 11:30:00.000    11
```

Comment: Could you try restating your algorithm again? You want hourly bands if they're consecutive but always resetting the starting time of a band after an hour to the next start point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative I: Will not catch the lone row 11, since it will try to pick the longest valid sequence from each starting point.

```
SELECT C.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        A.UID,
        A.TID AS TID1,
        MAX(B.TID) AS TID2
    FROM TblTask A
    INNER JOIN TblTask B
        ON B.UID = A.UID
        AND B.StartTime BETWEEN A.StartTime AND DATEADD(hour, 1, A.StartTime)
    GROUP BY A.TID, A.UID
    HAVING SUM(B.WId) >= 5 OR COUNT(*) >= 5
) Ranges
INNER JOIN TblTask C
    ON C.UID = Ranges.UID
    AND C.TID BETWEEN Ranges.TID1 AND Ranges.TID2
```

Alternative II: Will report both (4..9) and (4..10), since those fall within the criteria.

```
SELECT D.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        A.Uid,
        A.TID AS TID1,
        B.TID AS TID2
    FROM TblTask A
    INNER JOIN TblTask B
        ON B.Uid = A.Uid
        AND B.StartTime BETWEEN A.StartTime AND DATEADD(hour, 1, A.StartTime)
    INNER JOIN TblTask C
        ON C.UID = A.UID
        AND C.TID BETWEEN A.TID AND B.TID
    GROUP BY A.TID, B.TID, A.Uid
    HAVING SUM(C.WId) >= 5  OR COUNT(*) >= 5
) Ranges
INNER JOIN TblTask D
    ON D.Uid = Ranges.Uid
    AND D.TID BETWEEN Ranges.TID1 AND Ranges.TID2;
```

In either alternative, you could add columns from the `Ranges` table to distinguish between the concatenated sub-sequences.

Result of Alternative I:

```
TID   StartTime                 Uid   WId
  1   2011-06-06 09:30:00.000    10   1.5
  2   2011-06-06 09:40:00.000    10   3.5
  3   2011-06-06 09:50:00.000    10   1.0
  3   2011-06-06 09:50:00.000    10   1.0
  4   2011-06-06 10:45:00.000    10   2.5
  5   2011-06-06 10:50:00.000    10   1.5
  4   2011-06-06 10:45:00.000    10   2.5
  5   2011-06-06 10:50:00.000    10   1.5
  6   2011-06-06 10:55:00.000    10   0.0
  7   2011-06-06 11:30:00.000    10   0.0
  8   2011-06-06 11:35:00.000    10   0.0
  9   2011-06-06 11:40:00.000    10   0.0
 10   2011-06-06 11:43:00.000    10   0.0
  5   2011-06-06 10:50:00.000    10   1.5
  6   2011-06-06 10:55:00.000    10   0.0
  7   2011-06-06 11:30:00.000    10   0.0
  8   2011-06-06 11:35:00.000    10   0.0
  9   2011-06-06 11:40:00.000    10   0.0
 10   2011-06-06 11:43:00.000    10   0.0
  6   2011-06-06 10:55:00.000    10   0.0
  7   2011-06-06 11:30:00.000    10   0.0
  8   2011-06-06 11:35:00.000    10   0.0
  9   2011-06-06 11:40:00.000    10   0.0
 10   2011-06-06 11:43:00.000    10   0.0
 11   2011-06-06 11:20:00.000    11   7.0
 12   2011-06-06 11:30:00.000    11   1.0
```

Result of Alternative II:

```
TID   StartTime                 Uid   WId
  1   2011-06-06 09:30:00.000    10   1.5
  2   2011-06-06 09:40:00.000    10   3.5
  1   2011-06-06 09:30:00.000    10   1.5
  2   2011-06-06 09:40:00.000    10   3.5
  3   2011-06-06 09:50:00.000    10   1.0
  3   2011-06-06 09:50:00.000    10   1.0
  4   2011-06-06 10:45:00.000    10   2.5
  5   2011-06-06 10:50:00.000    10   1.5
  4   2011-06-06 10:45:00.000    10   2.5
  5   2011-06-06 10:50:00.000    10   1.5
  6   2011-06-06 10:55:00.000    10   0.0
  7   2011-06-06 11:30:00.000    10   0.0
  8   2011-06-06 11:35:00.000    10   0.0
  4   2011-06-06 10:45:00.000    10   2.5
  5   2011-06-06 10:50:00.000    10   1.5
  6   2011-06-06 10:55:00.000    10   0.0
  7   2011-06-06 11:30:00.000    10   0.0
  8   2011-06-06 11:35:00.000    10   0.0
  9   2011-06-06 11:40:00.000    10   0.0
  4   2011-06-06 10:45:00.000    10   2.5
  5   2011-06-06 10:50:00.000    10   1.5
  6   2011-06-06 10:55:00.000    10   0.0
  7   2011-06-06 11:30:00.000    10   0.0
  8   2011-06-06 11:35:00.000    10   0.0
  9   2011-06-06 11:40:00.000    10   0.0
 10   2011-06-06 11:43:00.000    10   0.0
  5   2011-06-06 10:50:00.000    10   1.5
  6   2011-06-06 10:55:00.000    10   0.0
  7   2011-06-06 11:30:00.000    10   0.0
  8   2011-06-06 11:35:00.000    10   0.0
  9   2011-06-06 11:40:00.000    10   0.0
  5   2011-06-06 10:50:00.000    10   1.5
  6   2011-06-06 10:55:00.000    10   0.0
  7   2011-06-06 11:30:00.000    10   0.0
  8   2011-06-06 11:35:00.000    10   0.0
  9   2011-06-06 11:40:00.000    10   0.0
 10   2011-06-06 11:43:00.000    10   0.0
  6   2011-06-06 10:55:00.000    10   0.0
  7   2011-06-06 11:30:00.000    10   0.0
  8   2011-06-06 11:35:00.000    10   0.0
  9   2011-06-06 11:40:00.000    10   0.0
 10   2011-06-06 11:43:00.000    10   0.0
 11   2011-06-06 11:20:00.000    11   7.0
 11   2011-06-06 11:20:00.000    11   7.0
 12   2011-06-06 11:30:00.000    11   1.0
```